# Jquery DateTime Picker Previous Time setting to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery Datetime Picker,all is running fine apart from the date.
I load the page in ASP.NET and set the datetime value from codebehind.

When i click on calender icon it load up the datetime but it sets the time to 00:00:00, however the date remain the same.

I have attached the screenshot.

http://tinypic.com/r/6ycfhu/5

after clicking calender icon
http://tinypic.com/r/15qzon5/5

How can i prevent this so when you click the calender icon it loads up the preselected time do not reset it to 00:00:00
Any advice/Help

Thank you.

Comment: Post your code where are wiring up the jQuery DateTime Picker to the DOM element.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#<%=reported.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
                showSecond: true,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
                stepHour: 2,
                stepMinute: 10,
                stepSecond: 10,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "../pics/cal.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
});

in code behind

reported.Value = rdr["DateReported"].ToString() == "" ? "" : (rdr["DateReported"].ToString() + " " + rdr["TimeReported"].ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution by myself
the following two functions will repopulate the date and time.and upon clicking it will not reset the time to 0.hence will load the time and put the sliders accordingly.

```
var lDate = "";
     var id = "";
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").hover(function () {
 var val = $(this).prev().val();
 lDate = val;
 id = $(this).prev().attr("id");
  });

         // SETTING DATETIME 
         $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function () {
             var v = lDate.split(' ');
             // $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').prev().val(lDate);
             var d = v[0].split('/');
             var t = v[1].split(':');
             $('#' + id).datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(d[2], d[1]-1, d[0], t[0], t[1], t[2]));
         });
```